# How can I select entries for a given weekday using SQL?

Tags: performance, sqlite

I could use this query to select all orders with a date on a monday:

```
SELECT * from orders WHERE strftime("%w", date)="1";
```

But as far as I know, this can't be speed up using an index, as for every row `strftime` has to be calculated.

I could add an additional field with the weekday stored, but I want to avoid it. Is there a solution that makes use of an index or am I wrong and this query actually works fine? (That means it doesn't have to go through every row to calculate the result.)

Comment: SQLite, but a possible solution could be to switch the database. (I'd not like that, though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want **all** Mondays ever, you'd need a field or sequential scan. What you could do, is calculate actual dates for example for all Mondays within a year. The condition `WHERE date IN ('2009-03-02', '2009-02-23', ...)` would use index

Comment: Wouldn't that be just as expensive as going through every table entry?

Comment: Not at all. There would be a lot fewer Mondays, then rows in the table. Moreover, those dates can be cached or stored.

Comment: It would use the index, assuming you have one, because you are dealing with complete dates.

Answer (score 1):

Or as an alternative to vartec's suggestion, construct a calendar table consisting only of a date and a day name for each day in the year (both indexed) and then perform your query by doing a JOIN against this table.