# How to select mondays with sqlite/sequel?

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sequel, dayofweek

In my SQLite-DB I want to select all entries on a monday.

How can I do it with Sequel?

A test example:

```
require 'sequel'

DB = Sequel.sqlite()#'test.db')
DB.create_table(:days) do
    String :text
    Date  :start
end

Date.today.upto(Date.today + 30){|d|
  DB[:days].insert( :text => d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d day %w in week %W"), :start => d)
}
```

How can I select all mondays?

In native [SQL I can do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602245/how-can-i-select-entries-for-a-given-weekday-using-sql):

```
select * from days where strftime("%w", start) = "1"
```

Using this, I can define a view and select for it:

```
DB.run('create view mondays as select * from days where strftime("%w", start) = "1"')
p DB[:mondays].all
```

But I would like to use it from Sequel.

I tried

```
sel = DB[:days].filter{ start.strftime("%w", :start) == '1' }  
#NoMethodError

sel = DB[:days].filter{ Sequel::SQL::Function.new(:strftime, "%w", :start) == '1' }
#SELECT * FROM `days` WHERE (1 = 0)
```

but without success.

Are there any other solutions?

I'm looking also for a possibility to select items by hour of day (all items with a timestamp, and then from 12:00-13:00 ...) I think this is the same problem and a solution for the day of week-selection will also solve my other problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the problems with your examples:

```
sel = DB[:days].filter{ start.strftime("%w", :start) == '1' }  
#NoMethodError
```

This uses a virtual row, so calling `start` returns a `Sequel::SQL::Identifier`.   The `Sequel::SQL::Identifier#strftime` method does not exist, hence the NoMethodError.

```
sel = DB[:days].filter{ Sequel::SQL::Function.new(:strftime, "%w", :start) == '1' }
#SELECT * FROM `days` WHERE (1 = 0)
```

This fails because you are using `==`.  Sequel doesn't override `==`, and ruby's default `==` returns `false`.  On SQLite, Sequel represents `false` as `(1 = 0)`.

This should work:

```
sel = DB[:days].filter{{strftime("%w", :start) => '1'}}
# SELECT * FROM `days` WHERE (strftime('%w', `start`) = '1')
```

This uses a hash (the inner {}) inside a virtual row block (the outer {}).  In Sequel, equality is represented by hashes.

Comment: Thanks again. I thought it must be something like I tried, but I didn't have the idea of the hash inside the block.

Comment: I tried your solution, but in my 'real case' I use `DateTime` and not `Date`. If I insert `d = DateTime.parse(d.strftime("%F %m:%d"))` before my insert in my example, it doesn't work. I make actually some experiments, perhaps there is a follow up question.

Comment: Ok, I found the solution. I have to add: `DB.use_timestamp_timezones = false`. Background information is in [sequel talk](http://osdir.com/ml/sequel-talk/2011-09/msg00014.html). One tripfall: The setting must be done before you add content (it doesn't work, if you already added entries with time zone settings on).